# Update SQL: не работает обновление базы данных

Tags: обновление, php, база-данных, mysql

Подскажите, почему не работает обновление базы данных? Вот код, когда он выполняется, почему-то данные удаляются, а не обновляются, в чем может быть проблема? Вот сам код:

```
<?php
include("bd.php");
if ($_POST['id']) {
    $id     = $_POST['id'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $id     = mysql_escape_String($id);
    echo "update users set status='$status' where id='$id'";
    mysql_query("update users set status='$status' where id='$id'");
}
?>
```

**UPD:**

```
$(function() 
{

$("h4").click(function() 
{
var titleid = $(this).attr("id");
var sid=titleid.split("title");
var id=sid[1];
var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
var parent = $(this).parent();
$(this).hide();
$("#formbox"+id).show();
return false;
});

$(".save").click(function() 
{
var A=$(this).parent().parent();
var X=A.attr('id');
var d=X.split("formbox");
var id=d[1];
var Z=$("#"+X+" input.content").val();
var dataString = 'id='+ id +'$status='+Z ;

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "status.php",

cache: false,
success: function(data)
{
A.hide(); 
$("#title"+id).html(Z); 
$("#title"+id).show(); 
}
});

return false;
});

$(".cancel").click(function() 
{
var A=$(this).parent().parent();
var X= A.attr("id");
var d=X.split("formbox");
var id=d[1];
var parent = $(this).parent();
$("#title"+id).show();
A.hide();

return false;
});

});
```

Код производит манипуляции с дивом, а потом ajax обновляет данные.

Comment: Вроде бы правильно, а что у тебя лежит в бд и что ты передаешь в параметрах?

Comment: Навскидку: если `id` - числовое, то кавычек не надо. И надо не мускль_эскейп_стринг, а intval()

Comment: Целочисленные значения лучше всего экранировать через `(int)$_POST['id']`, 
стринговые значения более правильно экранировать через `mysql_real_escape_string()`, а служебные слова SQL принято писать большими буквами: `UPDATE users SET status='$status' WHERE id=$id` (числовые переменные - без кавычек, текстовые - в кавычках) - так и сами не запутаетесь, и код будет более читабельным

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Проблема с кавыками - у тебя в запрос не подставляются значение переменных, поэтому запрос в базе ищет id=$id - как строку, и конечно ненаходит ее
Запрос должен выглядеть вот так

```
"update users set status='".$status."' where id='".$id."'"
```

2.Выведи на печать перед запросом значение переменных - они ваще есть?

Answer (score 2):

Для начала - в вашем случае, абсолютно не имеет значение, как вы запишите: или **id='".$id."'**, или **id='$id'**, или же просто **id=$id**. Запрос выдаст один и тот же результат.

---

Для того, чтоб не гадать где у вас может быть проблема, делайте проверку с выдачей как положительного результата, так и отрицательного.

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    // ...
} else {
    echo 'Параметра ID - ёк!';
}

//....

$res = mysql_query(' .... ');
if($res) {
    echo 'Прокатило;';
} else {
    echo 'Хьюстон! У нас проблемы!'.mysql_error();

}
```

Старайтесь названия функций писать правильно. Хоть и скушается mysql_escape_**S**tring , но всё же лучше всё с маленькой буквы. Но всё это лирическое отступление, а насторожило меня в вашем вопросе следующее:

> когда он выполняеться почему то данные
> удаляются а не обновляются

Вот с этого места, хотелось бы подробнее. Что значит удаляются? Удаляется запись из БД или удаляются данные в этой записи? *$_POST['status']* - это интовое значение или строка? Кроме *$_POST['status']*, есть еще другие данные, которые обновляют запись в таблице?

Comment: Статус это строка,при обновлении на ajax данные посылаются скрипту который должен занести данные в таблицу,но он наоборот их удаляет,нет нету обновляется только статус.

Comment: @raptor96, повторю вопрос... Cтатус - это строка? Потому что у меня подозрение, что это именно так. При работе есть проблемка с кодировкой. Я думаю, что это именно из-за этого. Кстати, а почему вы не экранируете данные со статусом?

Comment: ваши подозрения правильны по поводу того что статус это строка,а можно как нибудь при передаче устранить проблемы с кодировкой ?

Comment: Документы (в идеале) у вас должны быть в кодировке **UTF-8**. Если это так, то первое, что можно попробывать - это сразу после подключения к БД, дописать строку:

    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

Если лекарство не помогло, то попробуйте перекодировать данные статуса:

    $status = iconv('cp1251','utf-8',$_POST['status']);

При этом, возможно, что надо будет убрать сроку **mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");**

В общем, проблема у вас не с кавычками, как говорили коллеги выше (ставьте их спокойно на интовые значения), а с кашей в кодировке. Это я уже уверен.

Comment: P.S. И установите FireBug. Если бы этот плагин у вас был, то вы бы могли обратить внимание, что данные, которые вы передаете имею вид аля "**%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82**". Это сразу бы натолкнуло на мысль о кодировке.